# Create datafield with gmt-timezone timestamp in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I'm trying to convert a postgresql sql-query to mysql. Using a translator.

this is the query in postgres:

```
comment_date_gmt timestamp without time zone DEFAULT timezone('gmt'::text, now()) NOT NULL,
```

it's converted to

```
comment_date_gmt timestamp DEFAULT timezone('gmt',
```

The none-closed parenthesis is a sign that everything isn't right. I'm trying to figure out what this query should look like. Any suggestions?

Comment: What translator are you using? Sounds like an issue for their forum..

Comment: I've looked around a bit and it seems you can't really expect a 100% working postgres to mysql converter.

Comment: @KristofferNolgen: yeah, there are quite a few features in Postgres that MySQL lacks... In particular, using an expression as a default value like you're doing in Postgres.

Comment: Yeah, good luck converting a recursive CTE to MySQL ;-) . Some things can be done using MySQL variables, but only sometimes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only reliable SQL query dialect converter is the human brain.

Tools can be useful for the basics, like data type renaming, but lots of that sort of thing can be avoided by just writing the queries using standard types in the first place.

You'll have a very hard time converting a MySQL query that uses query variables to a PostgreSQL query, or converting a PostgreSQL (well, SQL-standard) recursive common table expression to something MySQL understands. The two have totally different stored procedure languages, different built-in functions, and all sorts of things. `array_agg`, `unnest`, etc ... most of that stuff would require translation to queries using MySQL variables where it's possible to do it at all. Then you've got window functions like `row_number`, `lead`, `lag`, and aggregates used as running windows like `sum(blah) OVER (...)`. A generic converter would need to "understand" the query to actually do the job.

A specific answer for the named problem isn't really possible since you haven't identified the converter tool.

At a guess, if you change the PostgreSQL query to:

```
comment_date_gmt timestamp without time zone DEFAULT (current_timestamp AT TIME ZONE 'utc') NOT NULL,
```

which is the standard phrasing understood by PostgreSQL and other compliant databases.